# How to call constructor of Eclipse 4 RCP part when application start?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a few Parts in one PartStack. When application start, only constructor of the first part is called. Other constructors are called when I click on these Parts.

I have something like this:

```
public class OneOfParts {
    @Inject OneOfParts(final BorderPane pane) {
        //some initialization stuff
    }
    //other methods
}
```

How can I call constructors of all Parts in this PartStack when application start?

E: Or is there another way to initialize final field from Parts when application start?

Comment: Parts are only created when they are become visible. Why do you want the constructors called?

Comment: Because I use in them method with \@Injject \@Optional which is called when I read file by fileChooser. I use each part for another types of files, so when I read txt file I need initializatied fields to show content in first Part (hex dump) and Part for txt.

Comment: It sounds like these values should not be in the Part but in some other object which is available to everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do your initializations during application start using a LifeCycleHandler. Lars Vogel describes how to implement one [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html).

Alternatively you could write a data class and annotate it with @Creatable and @Singleton which you then use in all parts sharing that data by DI.

```
@Singleton
@Creatable
public class SharedData() {

  private SharedData() {
    // initialize Data here - alternatively: Use @PostConstruct method in this class
  }

}

public class PartShowingHex {

  @PostConstruct
  private void initializePart(SharedData pData) {
    // do whatever you need
  }

}
```

For a field based approach:

```
public class PartShowingTxt {

  @Inject
  private SharedData myData;

  @PostConstruct
  private void initializePart() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

I'd recommand using the Data-Singleton with method-DI approach (first code example).